# Problems with MS Paint - Windows 7 64bit

Tags: microsoft-paint

Since loading the 'Live Box' in France my paint does not function. It will allow letters , delete , copy and paste but will not let me change colour or draw lines or shapes. I am not sure what else may be not working. I have tried re-start but to no avail. Live Box is the internet/telephone package provided by France Telecom - Orange. I wish that I did not have to use it but there seems no alternative. It also is causing the pointer to disappear occasionally, only restored with a shut down and re-start.

Comment: Can you expand on live box some, will make it easier to answer.